# d3 liquid water chart conversion from d3v3 to v4

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've built a d3.js liquid chart v3 which decouples it from the plugin used in the old demo here. http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6

[image]

d3js -- version 3 - Liquid chart
http://jsfiddle.net/dz36kjvc/

20th December
version4 - Here is my working version
http://jsfiddle.net/f975pnta/

```js
  var $this = $('.fillgauge');

      var w = $this.data("width");
      var h = $this.data("height");
      var ir = $this.data("innerradius");
      var r = $this.data("radius");




  function liquidChart(el, index){


      var width = $(el).data("width");
      var height = $(el).data("height");

      var radius = width/2;

        var displayText = $(el).data("display-text");
        var numberCurrent = $(el).data("number-current");
        var numberMax = $(el).data("number-max");
        var displayPercent = $(el).data("display-percent");

          var circleColor = $(el).data("circle-color");
          var textColor = $(el).data("text-color");
          var waveTextColor = $(el).data("wave-text-color");
          var waveColor = $(el).data("wave-color");
          var textVertPosition = $(el).data("text-vert-position");
          var textHorzPosition = $(el).data("text-horz-position");
          var waveAnimateTime = $(el).data("wave-animate-time");
          var overlayImage = $(el).data("overlay-image");
          var overlayImageHeight = $(el).data("overlay-image-height");
          var overlayImageWidth = $(el).data("overlay-image-width");

          var chartPaddingLeft = $(el).data("chart-padding-left");
          /*off center in case a handle is ever given to a cup*/

      var options = {
        "displayPercent": displayPercent,
          "displayText": displayText,
          "circleColor": circleColor,
          "textColor": textColor,
          "waveTextColor":waveTextColor,
          "waveColor":waveColor,
          "circleThickness":0,
          "textVertPosition":textVertPosition,
          "textHorzPosition":textHorzPosition,
          "waveAnimateTime":waveAnimateTime
      }   

      var config1 = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();
      config1=  $.extend(config1, options);

      //gauge1.update(NewValue());


    var chart = d3.select(el).append("svg:svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("padding-left", chartPaddingLeft+"px")
        .attr("id", "fillgauge"+index);
        

          var circle = chart.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", width/2)
      .attr("cy", height/2)
      .attr("r", radius)
      .attr("fill", circleColor);
              
         
      var gauge1= loadLiquidFillGauge("fillgauge"+index, numberCurrent, numberMax, config1);
    
    /*
    var imgs = chart.append("svg:image")
                .attr("xlink:href", overlayImage)
                .attr("x", "0")
                .attr("y", "0")
                .attr("width", overlayImageHeight)
                .attr("height", overlayImageWidth);*/

      function NewValue(){
          if(Math.random() > .5){
              return Math.round(Math.random()*100);
          } else {
              return (Math.random()*100).toFixed(1);
          }
      }
  }


  liquidChart($this[0], 0);
  


  /*!
   * @license Open source under BSD 2-clause (http://choosealicense.com/licenses/bsd-2-clause/)
   * Copyright (c) 2015, Curtis Bratton
   * All rights reserved.
   *
   * Liquid Fill Gauge v1.1
   */
  function liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings(){
      return {
          minValue: 0, // The gauge minimum value.
          maxValue: 100, // The gauge maximum value.
          circleThickness: 0.05, // The outer circle thickness as a percentage of it's radius.
          circleFillGap: 0.05, // The size of the gap between the outer circle and wave circle as a percentage of the outer circles radius.
          circleColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the outer circle.
          waveHeight: 0.05, // The wave height as a percentage of the radius of the wave circle.
          waveCount: 1, // The number of full waves per width of the wave circle.
          waveRiseTime: 1000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for the wave to rise from 0 to it's final height.
          waveAnimateTime: 18000, // The amount of time in milliseconds for a full wave to enter the wave circle.
          waveRise: true, // Control if the wave should rise from 0 to it's full height, or start at it's full height.
          waveHeightScaling: true, // Controls wave size scaling at low and high fill percentages. When true, wave height reaches it's maximum at 50% fill, and minimum at 0% and 100% fill. This helps to prevent the wave from making the wave circle from appear totally full or empty when near it's minimum or maximum fill.
          waveAnimate: true, // Controls if the wave scrolls or is static.
          waveColor: "#178BCA", // The color of the fill wave.
          waveOffset: 0, // The amount to initially offset the wave. 0 = no offset. 1 = offset of one full wave.
          textVertPosition: .5, // The height at which to display the percentage text withing the wave circle. 0 = bottom, 1 = top.
          textSize: 1, // The relative height of the text to display in the wave circle. 1 = 50%
          valueCountUp: true, // If true, the displayed value counts up from 0 to it's final value upon loading. If false, the final value is displayed.
          displayPercent: true, // If true, a % symbol is displayed after the value.
          textColor: "#045681", // The color of the value text when the wave does not overlap it.
          waveTextColor: "#A4DBf8" // The color of the value text when the wave overlaps it.
      };
  }

  function loadLiquidFillGauge(elementId, numberCurrent, numberMax, config) {
      if(config == null) config = liquidFillGaugeDefaultSettings();

      //value as it is

      var value = (numberCurrent/numberMax) * 100;;

      var textValue = numberCurrent;
      
      if(config.displayPercent){
        textValue = (numberCurrent/numberMax) * 100;
      }


      var gauge = d3.select("#" + elementId);
      var radius = Math.min(parseInt(gauge.style("width")), parseInt(gauge.style("height")))/2;
      var locationX = parseInt(gauge.style("width"))/2 - radius;
      var locationY = parseInt(gauge.style("height"))/2 - radius;
      var fillPercent = Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value))/config.maxValue;

      var waveHeightScale;
      if(config.waveHeightScaling){
          waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .range([0,config.waveHeight,0])
              .domain([0,50,100]);
      } else {
          waveHeightScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .range([config.waveHeight,config.waveHeight])
              .domain([0,100]);
      }

      var textPixels = (config.textSize*radius/2);
      var textFinalValue = parseFloat(textValue).toFixed(2);
      var textStartValue = config.valueCountUp?config.minValue:textFinalValue;
      var percentText = config.displayPercent?"%":"";
      var circleThickness = config.circleThickness * radius;
      var circleFillGap = config.circleFillGap * radius;
      var fillCircleMargin = circleThickness + circleFillGap;
      var fillCircleRadius = radius - fillCircleMargin;
      var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius*waveHeightScale(fillPercent*100);

      var waveLength = fillCircleRadius*2/config.waveCount;
      var waveClipCount = 1+config.waveCount;
      var waveClipWidth = waveLength*waveClipCount;

      // Rounding functions so that the correct number of decimal places is always displayed as the value counts up.
      var textRounder = function(value){ return Math.round(value); };
      if(parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))){
          textRounder = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1); };
      }
      if(parseFloat(textFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounder(textFinalValue))){
          textRounder = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2); };
      }

      // Data for building the clip wave area.
      var data = [];
      for(var i = 0; i <= 40*waveClipCount; i++){
          data.push({x: i/(40*waveClipCount), y: (i/(40))});
      }

      // Scales for drawing the outer circle.
      var gaugeCircleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0,2*Math.PI]).domain([0,1]);
      var gaugeCircleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0,radius]).domain([0,radius]);

      // Scales for controlling the size of the clipping path.
      var waveScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveClipWidth]).domain([0,1]);
      var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveHeight]).domain([0,1]);

      // Scales for controlling the position of the clipping path.
      var waveRiseScale = d3.scale.linear()
          // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
          // such that the it will overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
          // circle at 100%.
          .range([(fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2+waveHeight),(fillCircleMargin-waveHeight)])
          .domain([0,1]);
      var waveAnimateScale = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([0, waveClipWidth-fillCircleRadius*2]) // Push the clip area one full wave then snap back.
          .domain([0,1]);

      // Scale for controlling the position of the text within the gauge.
      var textRiseScaleY = d3.scale.linear()
          .range([fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2,(fillCircleMargin+textPixels*0.7)])
          .domain([0,1]);

      // Center the gauge within the parent SVG.
      var gaugeGroup = gauge.append("g")
          .attr('transform','translate('+locationX+','+locationY+')');

      // Draw the outer circle.
      var gaugeCircleArc = d3.svg.arc()
          .startAngle(gaugeCircleX(0))
          .endAngle(gaugeCircleX(1))
          .outerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius))
          .innerRadius(gaugeCircleY(radius-circleThickness));
      gaugeGroup.append("path")
          .attr("d", gaugeCircleArc)
          .style("fill", config.circleColor)
          .attr('transform','translate('+radius+','+radius+')');

      var textLeftPlacement = parseInt(radius + config.textHorzPosition, 10);

      if(config.displayText){
        // Text where the wave does not overlap.
        var text1 = gaugeGroup.append("text")
            .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
            .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
            .style("fill", config.textColor)
            .attr('transform','translate('+textLeftPlacement+','+textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition)+')');
      } 

      // The clipping wave area.
      var clipArea = d3.svg.area()
          .x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); } )
          .y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d.y*2*Math.PI));} )
          .y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius*2 + waveHeight); } );
      var waveGroup = gaugeGroup.append("defs")
          .append("clipPath")
          .attr("id", "clipWave" + elementId);
      var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
          .datum(data)
          .attr("d", clipArea)
          .attr("T", 0);

      // The inner circle with the clipping wave attached.
      var fillCircleGroup = gaugeGroup.append("g")
          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipWave" + elementId + ")");
      fillCircleGroup.append("circle")
          .attr("cx", radius)
          .attr("cy", radius)
          .attr("r", fillCircleRadius)
          .style("fill", config.waveColor);


      if(config.displayText){
        // Text where the wave does overlap.
        var text2 = fillCircleGroup.append("text")
            .text(textRounder(textStartValue) + percentText)
            .attr("class", "liquidFillGaugeText")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("font-size", textPixels + "px")
            .style("fill", config.waveTextColor)
            .attr('transform','translate('+textLeftPlacement+','+textRiseScaleY(config.textVertPosition)+')');
      }

      // Make the value count up.
      if(config.valueCountUp){
          var textTween = function(){
              var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, textFinalValue);
              return function(t) { this.textContent = textRounder(i(t)) + percentText; }
          };
          if(config.displayText){
            text1.transition()
                .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                .tween("text", textTween);
            text2.transition()
                .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                .tween("text", textTween);
          }
      }

      // Make the wave rise. wave and waveGroup are separate so that horizontal and vertical movement can be controlled independently.
      var waveGroupXPosition = fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2-waveClipWidth;
      if(config.waveRise){
          waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(0)+')')
              .transition()
              .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
              .attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(fillPercent)+')')
              .each("start", function(){ wave.attr('transform','translate(1,0)'); }); // This transform is necessary to get the clip wave positioned correctly when waveRise=true and waveAnimate=false. The wave will not position correctly without this, but it's not clear why this is actually necessary.
      } else {
          waveGroup.attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+waveRiseScale(fillPercent)+')');
      }

      if(config.waveAnimate) animateWave();

      function animateWave() {
          wave.attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(wave.attr('T'))+',0)');
          wave.transition()
              .duration(config.waveAnimateTime * (1-wave.attr('T')))
              .ease('linear')
              .attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(1)+',0)')
              .attr('T', 1)
              .each('end', function(){
                  wave.attr('T', 0);
                  animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime);
              });
      }

      function GaugeUpdater(){
          this.update = function(value){
              var newFinalValue = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
              var textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return Math.round(value); };
              if(parseFloat(newFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounderUpdater(newFinalValue))){
                  textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(1); };
              }
              if(parseFloat(newFinalValue) != parseFloat(textRounderUpdater(newFinalValue))){
                  textRounderUpdater = function(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2); };
              }

              var textTween = function(){
                  var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
                  return function(t) { this.textContent = textRounderUpdater(i(t)) + percentText; }
              };

              text1.transition()
                  .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                  .tween("text", textTween);
              text2.transition()
                  .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                  .tween("text", textTween);

              var fillPercent = Math.max(config.minValue, Math.min(config.maxValue, value))/config.maxValue;
              var waveHeight = fillCircleRadius*waveHeightScale(fillPercent*100);
              var waveRiseScale = d3.scale.linear()
                  // The clipping area size is the height of the fill circle + the wave height, so we position the clip wave
                  // such that the it will overlap the fill circle at all when at 0%, and will totally cover the fill
                  // circle at 100%.
                  .range([(fillCircleMargin+fillCircleRadius*2+waveHeight),(fillCircleMargin-waveHeight)])
                  .domain([0,1]);
              var newHeight = waveRiseScale(fillPercent);
              var waveScaleX = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveClipWidth]).domain([0,1]);
              var waveScaleY = d3.scale.linear().range([0,waveHeight]).domain([0,1]);
              var newClipArea;
              if(config.waveHeightScaling){
                  newClipArea = d3.svg.area()
                      .x(function(d) { return waveScaleX(d.x); } )
                      .y0(function(d) { return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI*2*config.waveOffset*-1 + Math.PI*2*(1-config.waveCount) + d.y*2*Math.PI));} )
                      .y1(function(d) { return (fillCircleRadius*2 + waveHeight); } );
              } else {
                  newClipArea = clipArea;
              }

              var newWavePosition = config.waveAnimate?waveAnimateScale(1):0;
              wave.transition()
                  .duration(0)
                  .transition()
                  .duration(config.waveAnimate?(config.waveAnimateTime * (1-wave.attr('T'))):(config.waveRiseTime))
                  .ease('linear')
                  .attr('d', newClipArea)
                  .attr('transform','translate('+newWavePosition+',0)')
                  .attr('T','1')
                  .each("end", function(){
                      if(config.waveAnimate){
                          wave.attr('transform','translate('+waveAnimateScale(0)+',0)');
                          animateWave(config.waveAnimateTime);
                      }
                  });
              waveGroup.transition()
                  .duration(config.waveRiseTime)
                  .attr('transform','translate('+waveGroupXPosition+','+newHeight+')')
          }
      }

      return new GaugeUpdater();
  }
```

```html
  <div class="fillgauge" 
          data-role="fillgauge" 
          data-height="155"
          data-width="155"
          data-chart-padding-left="0"
          data-display-percent=false
          data-display-text=false
          data-number-current=20
          data-number-max=70
          data-circle-color="grey" 
          data-text-color="black" 
          data-wave-text-color="black" 
          data-wave-color="gold" 
          data-text-vert-position=1
          data-text-horz-position=20
          data-wave-animate-time=1000
          data-overlay-image="./beer.png"
          data-overlay-image-height="155"
          data-overlay-image-width="155"
      ></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

there is a version 4 in the works - but I feel it missing a lot of features version 3 had. We able to import the other properties from that old codebase - there was so much other stuff like changing color of the water, speed, duration, some of them were overriden in a config object - we also able to change the variable names here to from alpha0,beta0 to more understable parts -- does this create just 1 wave object?

so on start the water is purple then turns blue -- but also rises from 0 level to where it needs to be -- like a themometer - so on start -- rather than the wave just begins -- it has those same kind of bits to it  I think the animation of it rising could do with some easing or something - it just shunts up -- if its water and its got some weight to it - it would rush in smoother? I think also some of the durations should still in be in mili seconds e.g. animate-time=1000 --- what do these 100000 constants represent eg.. "t / 100000" –

I still feel its missing older functionality -- "upgrade this old water chart from v3 to 4 -- clean up the code base - so it relies less on the old function code there -- really adapt this into something flexible -- so produce a rectangle or circle shell -- clean up the various data attributes -- earlier used defaultConfig object it bit confusing as to what should be an editable or fixed. create a working example with more details explained on how the waves are created/changed -"

"- rename the variables to more understandable words - eg. A0- height, Alpha2 - waterWaveHeight etc. if that's what its doing, version 3 code is lofty with a lot of different configuration parts - and uses more milisecond duration settings - so I am keen to inherit its properties/customization but having it working for v4 -- even prepare it for the option of multiple water waves behind each other to make it look like an oil lap -- different oils - colors/viscosity etc.. –" –

--

d3 -- version 4 - Liquid chart http://jsfiddle.net/yrkcpgj9

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let width = 480;
  const $this = $('#demo_container');
  let container = d3.select($this[0]);
  let svg = container.select('svg');
  let xmin = -10;
  let xmax = 10;
  let dx = 1;
  /**
   * Height of Container decided based on ymin and ymax values
   * Container Height = (startymax - startymin) * 24px
   * So, if startymin = 0 and startymax = 20 then Container Height will be 480px
   * 
   * Other thing ymin and ymax define are the height of full and empty part of container
   * startymax = 20 means Container is total empty
   * startymin = 0 means Container has no fluid
   *
   * if, startymin = -16 means Container is 80% full
   * startymax = 4 means Container is 20% empty
   */
  let startymin = ymin = 0; // Will animate to -16
  let startymax = ymax = 20; // Will animate to 4
  /**
   * Let's we want to animate from ymin 0 to -16 means fluid height from 0% to 80%
   * and ymax 20 to 4 means 100% empty to 20% empty container
   *
   * Total duration for this animation will be 10 Seconds
   */
  let endymin = -16;
  let endymax = 4;
  let duration = 10; // Seconds
  
  // How much fluid will change per millisecond
  let changePerMillisecond = ((startymin - endymin) / (1000 * duration));
  
  /**
   * Color Scheme
   * Start RGB - 800080 - Purple
   * End RGB - 0000FF - Blue
   *
   * So, R will go from 128 to 256
   * and B will go from 128 to 0
   */
  let startR = R = 128;
  let startB = B = 128;
  let color = `#${R.toString(16)}00${B.toString(16)}`;
  
  let colorChangePerMillisecond = ((startR - 0) / (1000 * duration));
  
  let dy = 1;
  let aspect = (ymax - ymin) / (xmax - xmin);

  let grid = d3
    .range(ymin, dy, dy)
    .map(y => d3.range(xmin - dx, xmax + 2 * dx, dx).map(x => [x, y]));
  grid = grid.reduce(function(accumulated, currentValue) {
    return accumulated.concat(currentValue);
  }, []);

  var HEIGHT_OF_WAVE = 0.2; // Height
  var SPACE_BW_WAVES = 0.42; // Space between waves
  var WAVE_SPEED = 6; // Speed

  let t0 = 0;
  let pts = grid.map(xy => p(HEIGHT_OF_WAVE, SPACE_BW_WAVES, WAVE_SPEED, xy[0], xy[1], t0));
  let outline = pts.slice(pts.length - (xmax - xmin + 3));
  outline.push([xmax, ymax]);
  outline.push([xmin, ymin]);

  let xScale, yScale, rScale, pts_to_path;
  function setup() {
    svg.selectAll('*').remove();
    let height = aspect * width;
    svg.attr('height', height);
    xScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([xmin, xmax])
      .range([0, width]);
    rScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, xmax - xmin])
      .range([0, width]);
    yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([ymin, ymax])
      .range([height, 0]);
    pts_to_path = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      });

    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr('d', pts_to_path(outline))
      .attr('fill', color);
  }

  function start(t) {
    let changed = false;

    if (ymin >= -16) {
      ymin = startymin - (t * changePerMillisecond);
      changed = true;
    }

    if (ymax >= 4) {
      ymax = startymax - (t * changePerMillisecond);
      changed = true;
    }
    
    if (R > 1) {
      R = parseInt(startR - (t * colorChangePerMillisecond));
    }
    
    if (B < 254) {
      B = parseInt(startB + (t * colorChangePerMillisecond));
    }
    
    color = `#${R > 15 ? R.toString(16) : `0${R.toString(16)}`}00${B.toString(16)}`;
    
    pts = grid.map(xy => p(HEIGHT_OF_WAVE, SPACE_BW_WAVES, WAVE_SPEED, xy[0], xy[1], t / 1000));
    outline = pts.slice(grid.length - (xmax - xmin + 3));
    outline.push([xmax, ymin]);
    outline.push([xmin, ymin]);
    
    if (changed) {
      setup();
    }
    
    svg
      .selectAll("path")
      .transition()
      .duration(0)
      .attr('d', pts_to_path(outline));
    svg
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(pts)
      .transition()
      .duration(0)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
      });
    
  }

  function p(A, alpha, beta, x0, y0, t) {
    let r = A * Math.exp(alpha * y0);
    let arg = alpha * x0 - beta * t;
    let x = x0 + r * Math.cos(arg);
    let y = y0 + r * Math.sin(arg);
    return [x, y];
  }

  setup();
  let timer = d3.timer(start);
});
```

```css
div.demo_container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
div.svg_container {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 2%;
}
svg.demo {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px lightslategray;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo_container" class="demo_container">
  <div id="water" class="svg_container">
    <svg id="water" class="demo" width=480></svg>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've got this far - http://jsfiddle.net/oebqr5u9/3/

Comment: Here is my working version 

http://jsfiddle.net/f975pnta/